# Error establishing a database connection: XAMPP WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, xampp

There's a lot of documentation on this but my troubleshooting has failed. I installed XAMPP for Windows which works fine but it is not working for my Mac OS Sierra.

My XAMPP version is 5.6.30-0 and my servers are running.

This is my wp-config.php details:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', ‘WP’);

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', ‘admin’);

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', ‘darkall’);

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

The user "admin" is a new user I created just for the "WP" database in      phpMyAdmin. [WP database exists in phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J52M5.png)

I tried to go to http://localhost/wp/ but get the error "Error establishing a database connection""

Comment: Could you replace curly quotes between WP, admin, darkall with single quotes and see if that's the issue?

Comment: Hi Cyto, Thank you very much for your reply. It worked. Apparently my Mac keyboard gives me those curly quotes by default. I should change that if possible. I do appreciate you prompt response `/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'WP');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'admin');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'darkall');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think two problems may occur this problem:

1: Adding curly braces to your db name , db username , db password .. Replace them with **' '** single quotion mark.

2: The database **username** or **password** is not matching. Recheck the **username** and **password** of your database or **reset** user credentials and go with default **username**  '**root**' with empty **password** Like below   :

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'WP');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', ‘root’);

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

You can also check database credentials using php db connection .. create a file called conn.php and add below codes to your file :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "darkall";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

If browser print **"Connected successfully"** then wordpress should work with this also.

Comment: So, problem was curly quotes?

Comment: Yes curly quotes. It is fixed. Cheers!

Comment: Just to mentioned a connection problem I've had before during local development was I needed to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost for DB_HOST.